# paymentMethodNonce not called in Braintree Drop-in Payment UI iOS v4

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to Braintree SDK. I followed this link https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/v4 . When I try to generate paymentMethodNonce I am not able to do it. The drop in UI is Displayed but it is not generating paymentMethodNonce. I tried BTDropInControllerDelegate but those delegate methods are not called. If any one is expert in this please suggest me how to get the paymentMethodNonce

Thanks in advance